# JPA Eclipselink Annotation Errors (@Entity, @Id)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a few SQL tables which I have connected to in Eclipse Neon EE in a dynamic web project.  I auto-generated Entity classes from the tables, which were mapped (using JPA) just fine.  However, I am getting errors and red underlines on all the JPA annotations (@Entity, @Table, @Id, etc.).  Will this affect my project in any way, or is it just Eclipse errors?

Comment: compile your project outside eclipse and you will know

Comment: why not look at the errors and see what they say?!